# Correlating two variables at different levels

Tags: regression, correlation

Imaginary example, but should work well for the purpose of this question:

I'm doing a simple linear regression (or a correlation, with 1 IV and 1 DV) for 2 variables, for example the number of steps in the staircase vs reported satisfaction of achieving the top by participants.
Let's say I'm taking 4 different staircases into account: 3-steps; 5-steps; 10-steps; and 50-steps high. The point is, this isn't a categorical, but a ratio scale (ignore the other problems with this sample of staircases, such as far-from-normal distribution, etc).

Now, let's say I have 10 participants climbing these staircases in random order each, and reporting their satisfaction in a number from 1 to 7.

There are 2 ways to analyse this data. One would be to average responses for each staircase. So say we get the results:

3-steps:  1.6

5-steps:  2.3

10-steps: 3.4

50-steps: 6.1

Our scatterplot would be very simple:

[image]

But maybe averaging the results is unnecessary and kills the variation in the data? We could leave the raw scores as they were and then plot them, like this:

[image]

How we approach it also affects Person's r (or Spearman's rho since we had non-normal distribution of stair number). Obviously degrees of freedom (and therefore p values) also change.

Is there a one-and-always-true definite answer to how this should be done?

Comment: You need the latter approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a harder question than it initially looks.  The relevant topic goes by different names depending on your disciplinary background.  Economists call the topic "random effects" or "random coefficients" or even "panel data."  Most social scientists call the topic ["multi-level modelling."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model)  Let's index your subjects by $i$ and your staircases by $j$.  Let's call the satisfaction by person $i$ after staircase $j$, $H_{ij}$ and the number of steps in staircase $j$, $P_j$.  Then the regression model looks like:
\begin{equation}
H_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_{1,i} P_j + \epsilon_{ij}
\end{equation}
The coefficient of interest is $\beta_{1,i}$.  This is the amount that person $i$'s satisfaction rises with each additional step.  Most often, you are interested in the average of this effect, $E\{\beta_i\}$---the answer to the question "By how much does satisfaction rise for an extra step, on average?"

What to do depends on what you believe about the statistical properties of $\beta_{1,i}$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$.  For example, if you believe that $\beta_{1,i}$ is exactly the same for each subject and if you believe that $\epsilon_{ij}$ is i.i.d., then Peter Flom's comment above is right.  Just run a simple regression of satisfaction on number of steps with each person-staircase as an observation.  It will give a good estimator for $\beta_1$ and the usual OLS standard errors are correct.

If you believe that $\beta_{1,i}$ is exactly the same for each subject and if you believe that $\epsilon_{ij}$ is correlated within staircases but uncorrelated within individuals, then your first procedure will give a good estimator, but the standard errors will be conservative.  Your second procedure will again give a good estimator, but the standard errors will be too narrow.

If you believe a more complicated thing about $\beta_{1,i}$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$ than either of the above ideas, then you have to learn something about multi-level modelling.  Still, however, the simple OLS estimator will be a pretty good estimator of the average of the $\beta_{1,i}$.  The only real issue is getting the standard errors right.